# Set default gid in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

What is the best way to set the default gid for plot elements in matplotlib? I want to completely get rid of the unpredictable gid's when saving svg figures, and set them to sensible, predictable values such as 'xaxis', 'xtick1', 'xtick2', 'curve1', 'legend1' etc. Without having lots of boilerplate code for each separate figure, of course.

I would be happy to subclass the relevant part of matplotlib and write code for this, but matplotlib is pretty big and I am not sure where to start.

Comment: This is an excellent question in the sense that I too would like to know the answer. You may have better luck posting on the MatPlotLib users mailing list: https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/matplotlib-users

Comment: Also, you may want to add the results of your research, however cursory it may be. You will need to be pretty familiar with relevant aspects of the code base to make meaningful changes anyway, so may as well start now. Here's a good place to start reading about backends: https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend. That whole faq is great actually.

Comment: The gid is set at the [`open_group` function](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/a5d92542163e86d9a7427141d15afe4a992198ca/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_svg.py#L533) within the svg backend. However I don't think it's worth to change the complete code here. Maybe the actual problem you want to solve is more simple and can be tackled by using the `.set_gid` method of the various artists.

Comment: Another possible solution would be if matplotlib allowed to set class attributes in addition to the id.

Comment: Again, if you tell us the *actual*  problem you would like to solve, there might be a solution. Otherwise the answer is indeed to rewrite the `RendererSVG`'s  `open_group` function and/or to extend most of the matplotlib artists with a custom attribute (the latter would involve changing a lot of code actually).

Comment: The actual problem is that I want svg figures to follow the website theme. By far the most elegant (but apparently not the easiest) solution is css to style the svg, but this cannot be done if the gid is not known.